# Facebook chat bot sending same message multiple times (Python)

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-chat, facebook-chatbot

I am working on a facebook mini-chat bot and I am encountering a problem which consists on the bot to receive the same message over and over even though it has already answered the message.

[it keeps receiving the same text from FB and replying to it over and over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqDXo.png)

```
def message_handler(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

    if data and data['object'] == 'page':
        for pageEntry in data['entry']:
            print "nombre de message", len(pageEntry['messaging'])
            for messagingEvent in pageEntry['messaging']:

                if messagingEvent.get('optin'):
                    print "optin", messagingEvent
                    receivedAuthentication(messagingEvent)
                elif messagingEvent.get('message'):
                    print "message", messagingEvent
                    receivedMessage(messagingEvent)
                elif messagingEvent.get('delivery'):
                    print "delivery", messagingEvent
                    receivedDeliveryConfirmation(messagingEvent)
                elif messagingEvent.get('postback'):
                    print "postback", messagingEvent
                    receivedPostback(messagingEvent)
                else:
                    print "UnHandled"
   return HttpResponse(status=200)

def receivedMessage(event):
   senderID = event.get('sender').get('id')
   message = event.get('message')

   messageText = message.get('text')
   messageAttachments = message.get('attachments')

   if messageText:
        if messageText == 'image':
            sendImageMessage(senderID)

        elif messageText == 'button':
            sendButtonMessage(senderID)

        elif messageText == 'generic':
            sendGenericMessage(senderID)

        elif messageText == 'receipt':
            sendReceiptMessage(senderID)
        elif messageText == 'hey':
           sendTextMessage(senderID, "Get it. Gimme a moment to process it :). Will get back to you in a moment")
           send_seen()
           send_typing()
           words = words_gen()
           sendTextMessage(senderID, words)


def callSendAPI(messageData):
    requests.post(
           url='https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=' + config.page_token,
          data=json.dumps(messageData),
        headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"}
    )
```

I get that I need to send a status 200 every time, which I did but still receiving the same text over and over

Here are the events I am subscribed to

> conversations, message_deliveries, message_reads, messages, messaging_optins, messaging_postbacks, picture

I removed **messaging_echoes** because I thought it was the problem turned out to not

Comment: I doubt this is your issue, but for me whenever I have an error, facebook sends the message several times at increasing intervals of time. Figured I'd mention it.

Comment: @user2322082 the thing is in the logs I can see that I'm receiving the same text multiple times so the bot is treating it again and again

Comment: If you include the print statements that show when you send a single message in your question, it may help people solve your issue

Comment: @user2322082 thinking about it, might be the **20s** reply frame that's the issue, I reduce the size of the dictionary to speed up the word_gen() and the issue seems to be gone

Comment: Interesting, I'm curious. Were you under 20 seconds and still having the issue? But now that you're under like say 3 seconds the issue is gone? Or were you just over 20 seconds

Comment: @user2322082 I was over the 20s as the generator was taking 40s in avg to process, now I'm at 12s in avg and the issue is gone

Comment: @kaizer Could you also look at my code I have the same issue. But I don't want to solve it that way of creating a database. Did u find any other way to solve it ?? I always thought it was because of the python not sending a status 200 to FB webhook. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848406/facebook-webhook-maiking-multiple-calls-for-the-same-message

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this issue by writing a function and checking duplicate messages in my Web API service.

Here I am generating message unique id either by payload or message received from Facebook which user clicks or types and then comparing with earlier stored unique value from concurrent dictionary.

_messageUniqueKeysBySender is ConcurrentDictionary and I am caching values by Sender Id for 30 minutes.

```
private bool IsDuplicate(Messaging messaging)
    {
        var messageUniqueId = string.Empty;
        var messageMessaging = messaging as MessageMessaging;
        if (messageMessaging != null)
            messageUniqueId = messageMessaging.Message.Id + messageMessaging.Message.SequenceNumber;
        else if (messaging is PostbackMessaging)
            messageUniqueId = ((PostbackMessaging)messaging).Postback.Payload +
                              ((PostbackMessaging)messaging).TimestampUnix;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageUniqueId)) return false;
        string existingUniqueId;
        if (_messageUniqueKeysBySender.TryGetValue(messaging.Sender.Id, out existingUniqueId))
        {
            if (existingUniqueId == messageUniqueId)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                _messageUniqueKeysBySender.TryUpdate(messaging.Sender.Id, messageUniqueId, existingUniqueId);
                return false;
            }
        }
        _messageUniqueKeysBySender.TryAdd(messaging.Sender.Id, messageUniqueId);
        return false;
    }
```

And then by checking in main code

```
try
        {
            if (!IsDuplicate(messaging))
            {
                var conversation = _conversationRepository[messaging.Sender.Id] ?? new Conversation(messaging.Sender.Id);
                message = await _bot.RespondToMessagingAsync(conversation, messaging);
                _conversationRepository[messaging.Sender.Id] = conversation;
                _logger.ForContext("FacebookMessage", messagingJson).LogDuration("Processing Facebook message", sw);
            }
            else
                _logger.ForContext("FacebookMessage", messagingJson).Warning("Duplicate message skipped");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.ForContext("FacebookMessage", messagingJson).Error(ex, "Failed to process message");
            message = new TextMessage(Resources.Error);
            hasError = true;
        }
```

Comment: Could you also look at my code I have the same issue. But I don't want to solve it that way of creating a database. Did u find any other way to solve it ?? I always thought it was because of the python not sending a status 200 to FB webhook. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848406/facebook-webhook-maiking-multiple-calls-for-the-same-message