# get_started button sends messaging_postbacks callbacks thrice

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger-bot

Hi I am using nodejs and developing a bot on facebook messenger platform. I have my webhook subscribed only to `messages` and `messaging_postbacks` events. However, when I test the bot, it seems to send callback three times. This is my webhook code

```
server.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
   let postback = req.body.entry[0].messaging[0].postback;
   if (postback.payload === 'Greet User'){
    console.log(postback);
   }
}
```

When I test my bot, the postback object gets printed thrice as below.

```
{ payload: 'Greet User', title: 'Get Started' }
{ payload: 'Greet User', title: 'Get Started' }
{ payload: 'Greet User', title: 'Get Started' }
```

Any help how to avoid it? I read in some of the posts here that I should deselect `message_reads` and `message_deliveries` subscriptions. But I do not have those selected anyways. Not sure what else I am missing? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem after some more searching on the net and debugging it myself. In case, if others reading this might be interested to know, the issue was I was not sending back 200 status back to facebook. I found the hint regarding the need to do that in this stack overflow post.

[Facebook webhook making multiple calls for the same message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848406/facebook-webhook-making-multiple-calls-for-the-same-message)

After sending the 200 response, I m not getting this issue. So relieved :)